# Exe file not working in other PC when database details is encrypted VB2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I created a desktop application using VB 2013 and one of the requirements is to encrypt the App.config file - the file in where the database connection details (username, password) is saved.

Before encryption of the App.config, I can run the .exe file in other pc (literally copy-paste the .exe file) but after encryption it's not working. Am I missing something?

This is what's inside my App.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
        <EncryptedData>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>encrypted_data_random_characters</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>encrypted_data_random_characters</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How are you encrypting the config file? What are you doing in your exe to decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

The DPAPI is machine specific. Part of the point is that something encrypted on one machine cannot be decrypted on another machine. If you want to be able to encrypt once and decrypt anywhere then you will need to use some other option. I had links to these pages:

[How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx)

[How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx)

in this thread:

[Protected Configuration (Encrypting Config Files)](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768)

from some time ago. They may outdated now but they show the difference between the two options even back then. You may need to look for a modern version/equivalent of the RSA option or else encrypt on the machine you want to decrypt on.